# maximum time exceeds when saving a model in app service provider class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

When I try to change product status after product quantity got updated in the database using database events in AppServiceProvider class, it causes Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded error.

The AppServiceProvider is like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use App\Product;
use App\Mail\UserCreated;
use App\Mail\UserMailChanged;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        Product::updated(function($product) {
            if ($product->quantity == 0 && $product->isAvailable()) {
                $product->status = 'unavailable';
                $product->save();
            }
        });

        User::created(function($user) {
            retry(5, function() use ($user) {
                Mail::to($user)->send(new UserCreated($user));
            }, 100);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your update function, you call `$product->save();`. This will trigger the update function. There is your endless loop.

You can change the if to:

```
if ($product->quantity == 0 && $product->isAvailable() && $product->status != 'unavailable') {
```

That way, the save will only be called once.